# React: TypeError: .map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, api

I'm trying to display a list of employees from an API with react , but when I'm trying to change an existing email, or a name I get this error ..
[image]

I don't know how to fix it.. my "employee" is and array not a string.

Thank you !

Comment: Could you please add more information?

Comment: Can you try to map your employeList like: employeeList.map(employee => ... is this working?

Comment: Are you waiting for the fetch to be finished before you use the .map function, if not you should add a if statement to wait or a .?

Comment: @Marci no, it's not working.. I don't know why..  is there a possibility that there is a problem because on the backend "employee" is an object and on the frontend "employee" is an array?

Comment: What are the results of console.log(employee) ? Also, if you console.log(typeof employee) ?

Comment: the typeof employee is "object"

Comment: Ok - so that means it could be an object or an array - what about the results of this: console.log(Array.isArray(employee)) - is this true or false?

Comment: @Mando it's 'true'

Answer (score 0):

or

```
const employeelist = employee !== "undefined" ? employee.map(employee=> {
    return(
      ///write your code
    )
}) : "null"
```

occuring type error is that type of employee is not object.
maybe firstly it is undefined.
So it is working follow by those.
Thanks